# Using Batch: Need to Read Multiple Numbers (Printed on Separate Lines) from a Text File and Adding them Together

Tags: batch-file, input, scripting, sum

I've got a text file that's created by a batch script and it prints 4 numbers on separate lines:

```
406364
406959
405509
406585
```

Now I need to read these 4 numbers from the file and add them together.
I've been trying to use variations of the following code (but with no success):

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%i in (%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Count_Tue05-31-2016@10-22-23.25.txt) do call :process %%i %%j %%k %%l
:process
set VAR1=%1
set VAR2=%2
set VAR3=%3
set VAR4=%4
REM echo %VAR1%
set sum=%VAR1%+%VAR2%+%VAR3%+%VAR4%
echo %sum%
goto :EOF
```

Can someone please help me out with this?

UPDATE:

I tried out:

```
for /F %%i in (file.txt) do set /A sum+=%%i
```

This gives me a different answer every single time, and none of them are correct (it should give 1625417).
[Different Answers Every Single Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFgQB.jpg)

Comment: `for /F %%i in (file.txt) do set /A sum+=%%i`

Comment: That gives me a different answer every single time, and none of them are correct.

Comment: @nauf: that's because you never reset `%sum%`. `set sum=0` before the `for`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I see someone answers prior than me.

Aacini gave you a working example, every time you run the script it adds the content of the var sum plus the contents of the file (1625417, 3250834, 4876251, 6501668, 8127085...). You must clear the sum variable each time.

Try

```
@echo off
set/a sum=0
for /F %%i in (file.txt) do set /A sum+=%%i
echo %sum%
```